# Return response from HTTPWebRequest somehow?

Tags: windows-phone-7, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to validate a user in my WP7 app by validating username/pass on a server.

In my "validate user" method I create a HTTPWebRequest with the stuff I need validated.

Then as far as I can see, the only option to execute is to use request.BeginGetResponse, with an async callback.

But I want to return the response from the request in the same method that I created the request in, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

`BeginGetResponse` returns an `IAsyncResult` which has a wait handle that is signalled when the request completes. All you have to do is wait on this handle: [ doesn't work on WP7 ]

---

UPDATE: use a `ManualResetEvent`

```
var mre = new ManualResetEvent( false );

var iar = myHttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse( state => mre.Set(), null );

mre.WaitOne();

var response = myHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse( iar );
```

Comment: As far as I've been able to read, and now have tested, the AsyncWaitHandle isn't supported on WP7 :(
It throws a NotSupportedException.

Comment: What happens if you just delete the wait and call EndGetResponse? It should block until the response is available.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use a `ManualResetEvent` - is that supported?

Comment: That just freezes the app, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would like to make it return in the calling method. I would just use the standard [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) behavior like below:

```
public void ValidateUser()
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
}

void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //Validate result from response by using e.Result
}
```

Comment: I want to call a method in my UI layer that validates the user. But all the HTTP logic should'nt be placed in the UI layer, looks bad, so how can I pass the value from my "service" class to the UI layer and act upon it?

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to achieve what you need would be to create an event in your worker class, and fire that event when the async call completes, so (pseudocode)...

```
void StartDownload(object[] parameters)
{
    var req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
    req.BeginGetRequestStream(Completed_handler, req);
}

void Completed_handler(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    var response = request.EndGetResponse(result);

    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
        NotifyCallerOfContent(contents)
    }
}

public event EventHandler<MyCustomEventArgsClass> DownloadHasFinished;

public NotifyCallerOfDownload(string content)
{
    if(null != DownloadHasFinished)
    {
        DownloadHasFinished(this, new MyCustomEventArgsClass(content));
    }
}
```

and then subscribe to the DownloadHasFinished event in your calling class.

As for calling out specifically by a HttpWebRequest, take a look at [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8/), where you will find some working samples.

Comment: That's a little out of my league, code experience/knowledge vise im afraid, but thanks though.

Comment: That's a shame - it is pretty much the only reliable way to get what you need.